# Client Side MVC Frameworks (Backbone, Knockout, etc.) and Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am experimenting with different client side MVC frameworks right now (mainly Backbone and Knockout). I am trying to come up with a way to validate. I have MVC 4 Web API that returns data only. All view engine logic is on the client side. Obviously, I understand that server-side validation is a must. This, I achieve with DataAnnotations and standard ASP.NET MVC validation through model binding.

However, I ended up with duplicating all validation logic now on the client side as well. Is there a way to return data but with validation logic attached to it?

Answer (score 5):

Blast-Dan is partially right, meaning that you cannot pass extra data to your server from the client aside from Key-Value pairs.

What you can do, however, is propagate your DataAnnotations to the client so that some validation code does not need to be rewritten. It is not trivial for complex rules, but the Html.EditorFor helpers will help you generate text boxes for input with attached validation attributes that are picked up seamlessly by jquery validation and stop the form submitting. 
I am thinking about [Required], [Range()] and [RegularExpression()] Data Annotations to name a few.

You can see a quick example if you just create a normal model and then add the Controller in Visual Studio using the wizard to create the Views for CRUD operations. You will see how the Data Annotations you used in the Model class end up being rendered on the output html.

If you are creating the HTML yourself without HtmlHelper (which I think you may be doin given the knockout tag) you may want to check the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider and the IClientValidatable interface starting from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834015%28v=vs.108%29).

As you can see, this is still uncharted territory tho :/

Comment: More on how this is accomplished using unobtrusive javascript can be found at Brad Wilson's blog [here for validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) and [here for events](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I am working with the scenario where the server only returns JSON data. No view engine logic exists on the server side. I was considering using a client side view engine (handle bars, mustache, etc.).

Comment: usually for simple validations (required fields, data types, etc) i use something like the jquery validation plugin; unfortunately those have to be recreated in the browser, but you'll find it pretty easy since you don't have to deal with all that unobtrusive hooha. For complex validation, I usually do those on the server and provide feedback in a json response and display in my template, and/or use remove validation in the same plugin. Agreed, data annotations are the way to go on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

No,

When giving data to the serer you need to use the HTTP protocol you will use a Post or Get method. this can only pass Key Value pairs. Using the MVC data Binding you are able to bind these Key Value pairs to create complex object.

However there is no way to transfer metadata or functions to C# in order to complete validation. All Validation logic needs to be written on both the server and a client side scripting language in order to provide proper validation